# Remove "Places" and "Applications" from Dash to Panel in GNOME shell on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I'm wondering how to remove applications and places from the dash to panel bar at the bottom of the screen. I'm able to remove the applications menu using "remove panel app menu" however whenever I logout or reboot it returns and I have to turn the "remove panel app menu" add on on and off again. As for the places menu I can't seem to get it to disappear even by turning places status indicator on and off.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> `['user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com', 'arc-menu@linxgem33.com', 'battery-percentage@nohales.org', 'turnoffdisplay@simonthechipmunk.noreply.com', 'shell-volume-mixer@derhofbauer.at', 'show-desktop-button@amivaleo', 'pulseaudio-equalizer@s8dragon.vn', 'AdvancedVolumeMixer@harry.karvonen.gmail.com', 'redshift@tommie-lie.de', 'weather-extension@xeked.com', 'weatherintheclock@JasonLG1979.github.io', 'hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca', 'Hide_Activities@shay.shayel.org', 'gnome-shell-screenshot@ttll.de', 'RemovePanelAppMenu']`

Comment: Hi, Welcome to AskUbuntu. are you using Dash to Panel Gnome Shell Extension?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using but I have the applications menu disabled in dash to panel otherwise there would be two applications icons. I'm also using arc menu as I prefer it to "applications".

Comment: can you attach a screen shot

Comment: The second picture is what I want (if I could also remove places) but I need to toggle the remove panel app menu extension on and off and seemingly I have to do this after every reboot.

Comment: Please include information on all extensions you use in your main question. This is essential information because the combination of extenstions might be the cause of issues you see. In your case, I am pretty sure that it is the Arc menu extension that is causing the issue here. Apparently, that extension likes to reset certain settings upon startup so that your preferences are not maintained. That is also the extension that provides the Places menu, I suppose.

Comment: I don't think the arc menu has anything to do with the places menu.

Comment: @Vinnie Ross Then another extension is providing this. You need to provide detail if you want someone else to solve your issue.

Comment: vanadium I added the details of all the extensions I'm using

Comment: Hey PRATAP I was able to locate the files for both apps menu and  places in usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions. Do you recommend I delete these if so how do I get authority to do so?

Comment: @VinnieRoss Ok, thats fine. `sudo nautilus /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` you can delete them, it will not harm..its almost like uninstalling. you can freshly install.

Comment: @VinnieRoss i should mention it before to check in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` but i ignored it, as many extensions will prefer to go into user account that is `home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/` extensions

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tweaks > Extensions > Places Status Indicator --> Toggle this to off.

---

Go to Tweaks > Extensions > Applications menu --> Toggle this to off.